# MATLAB uitable - Rows' Column Label

Tags: matlab, uitableview, header, label

I am looking to figure out how I can "label" the "Rows-Column" in my MATLAB uitable. See below image - looking to insert a header above 'Batch 1'.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!!

[Example of the table I am creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP0g6.png)

Comment: i am also looking for the same, but didn't find the answer :(

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I still have yet to figure out how to do this. Maybe an upvote for more visibility? ;)